Let B be the Borel subsets of R. For B ∈ B define µ(B) = 1 if (0, ε) ⊂ B for some ε > 0, µ(B) = 0 if not; Show that µ is not finitely additive on B
I'm beginning to learn probability theory, but was unsure if my solution for this problem is valid. I'm fairly unsure about my understanding of borel sets and measures, and would really appreciate if someone could take a look at it:
Problem:
Let β be the Borel subsets of R. For B ∈ β define µ(B) = 1 if (0, ε) ⊂ B for some ε > 0, µ(B) = 0 if not;  Show that µ is not finitely additive on β
Proof:
Suppose not. Suppose µ is finitely additive on β. Let ε>0. Then, let A be the borel subset (0, ε / 2), B be the singleton {ε/2}, and C be the borel subset (ε / 2, ε). Then, (0, ε) ⊂ A ∪ B ∪ C, so µ(A ∪ B ∪ C) = 1. However, µ(A ∪ B) = 0 and µ(C) = 0, so µ(A ∪ B ∪ C) != µ(A ∪ B) + µ(C). Thus, contradiction.

µ(A ∪ B) is not 0.  Note that µ just requires there to exist some ε, there isn't a single fixed value of ε.

gotcha - would a valid proof then be for A to be the set of irrational numbers in [0,1], and B to be the set of rational numbers in [0,1]? then µ(A) = µ(B) = 0 but µ(A ∪ B) = 1

All you need is a single counter-example and the one you supplied in a comment to my soon-to-be-deleted incorrect answer works. Take $A = [0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ and $B = [0, 1] \setminus A$, then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $\mu(A) = \mu(B) = 0$ but $\mu(A \cup B) = 1$. You should write this up as an answer to your own question (which is perfectly good practice on MSE).

Rob Arthan: I understand some of your answer but could you explain why $\mu(B) = 0$. Thanks.
